# Tricky data entry validation SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, while-loop, cursor, logic

I'm trying to develop a query to validate user data entry and I'm stuck. Basically, we're working with information about a daily 24 hour composite water sample. The user will enter the "COLDATE" which is the end of the composite and is stored in DATETIME format like "2015-03-02 04:00:00.000". Then they will enter the "Compstartdate" which is varchar(8) and looks like "03/02/15". Finally, they will enter the "Compstarttime" which is varchar(5) and looks like "04:01".

Don't blame me, I didn't set it up this way and let's assume that fixing the data types is not an option.

The rule that I am dealing with is that the "Compstart(date/time)" for one day needs to match the "COLDATE" for the previous day. So far, I can only figure out how to see if the "COLDATE(day) - 1 day" is equal to the "Compstartdate(day)". In other words, I can easily do logical comparisons within one record but I have no idea how to compare two records.

Also, we're only talking about 2000 records so performance considerations are not important, as evidenced by my use of a case statement. By this I mean that a solution which involves a cursor or while-loop would be perfectly acceptable to me.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT S.[SAMPNO]
      ,S.[LOCCODE]
      ,S.[COLDATE]
      ,U.[Compstartdate]
      ,U.[Compstarttime]

  FROM [dbo].[SAMPLE] as S
  JOIN [dbo].[SUSERFLDS] as U
  on S.SAMPNO = U.SAMPNO

  Where 
    Case
        When DATEPART(DAY, Convert(VARCHAR(10),U.Compstartdate,101)) != 
             DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, -1, S.COLDATE))

        Then 'Yes' 

        ELSE 'NO'

    END ='YES'
```

Edit: Let me try to explain the problem better. If I collect a 24-hour composite sample today and enter the information about the sample into the database, I'm going to enter the date/time that I collected the sample(end of composite) and the date/time that the composite started. Because it is a 24 hour composite, the start date/time of today's sample should equal the end time(COLDATE) of yesterday's sample. So I need to take two samples with the same LOCCODE but with COLDATE one day apart. Then see if the COLDATE for the earlier sample is equal to the Compstartdate/time of the later sample.

Edit #2: Here is some sample data.

```
create table [SAMPLE] (
  SAMPNO   int,
  LOCCODE  char(7),
  COLDATE  datetime
);

create table SUSERFLDS (
 SAMPNO        int,
 Compstartdate char(8),
 Compstarttime char(5)
);

SET DATEFORMAT mdy;


insert into [SAMPLE] values (11,'Sample1','2015-03-02 04:00:00.000');
insert into [SAMPLE] values (12,'Sample1','2015-03-03 04:00:00.000');
insert into [SAMPLE] values (13,'Sample1','2015-03-04 04:00:00.000');
insert into [SAMPLE] values (14,'Sample1','2015-03-05 04:00:00.000');

insert into SUSERFLDS values (11, '03/01/15', '04:00');
insert into SUSERFLDS values (12, '03/02/15', '04:00');
insert into SUSERFLDS values (13, '03/03/15', '05:00');
insert into SUSERFLDS values (14, '03/04/15', '04:00');
--Compstartdate/time for SAMPNO 12
--does match COLDATE for SAMPNO 11
--Compstartdate/time for SAMPNO 13 
--should match COLDATE for SAMPNO 12
```

Comment: _"I can easily do logical comparisons within one record but I have no idea how to compare two records."_ Do you mean you can compare day but need to compare time too?

Comment: While it is true that I need to compare the date and time elements, that is not what I meant by "compare two records." I meant that I do not know how to compare data from one day with data from the previous day which would appear as a separate record/row in the joined table.

Comment: I assume it is SQL Server. What version?

Comment: It is SQL server 2008.

Comment: Do you know if `Compstartdate` and `Compstarttime` are always valid values (a valid date and a valid time)? It makes a difference if you can assume that they will convert correctly.

Comment: Do your tables [SAMPLE] and [SUSERFLDS] also include a date-when-record-created field? If not, then on what basis can you separate data from one day with data from the previous day?

Comment: @Turophile, yes, there is a different query that I run to check for invalid dates and times.

Comment: @MattClarke, yes, the COLDATE stands for the sample collection data and would differentiate the two samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Here is the query that gives me what I was looking for:

```
set dateformat mdy;
With CTE1 as 
(
Select  S1.SAMPNO as SAMPNO1
        ,S1.COLDATE as COLDATE1
        ,S1.LOCCODE as LOCCODE1
        ,CAST( U1.Compstartdate +' '+ U1.Compstarttime as datetime) as Compstart1
From [SAMPLE] as S1 join
    [SUSERFLDS] as U1 on S1.SAMPNO = U1.SAMPNO
),
CTE2 as 
(
Select  S2.SAMPNO as SAMPNO2
        ,S2.COLDATE as COLDATE2
        ,S2.LOCCODE as LOCCODE2
        ,CAST( U2.Compstartdate +' '+ U2.Compstarttime as datetime) as Compstart2
From [SAMPLE] as S2 join
    [SUSERFLDS] as U2 on S2.SAMPNO = U2.SAMPNO
)
SELECT LOCCODE1
      ,SAMPNO1
      ,SAMPNO2
      ,COLDATE1
      ,COLDATE2
      ,Compstart1
From CTE1 join
        CTE2 on LOCCODE1 = LOCCODE2 and 
            COLDATE2 = DATEADD(Day, -1, COLDATE1)
Where Compstart1 != COLDATE2
```

Let me know if you see any fatal flaws.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused - there is no need to loop through the table - that's effectively what the join does.

Sadly SQLFiddle seems to be having difficulties at the moment. This is what I was going to set up as an example:

```
create table SAMPLE (
  SAMPNO   int,
  LOCCODE  char(1),
  LOCDESCR char(1),
  LOGBATCH char(1),
  LOGUSER  char(1),
  COLDATE  datetime
);

create table SUSERFLDS (
 SAMPNO        int,
 Compstartdate char(8),
 Compstarttime char(5)
);

SET DATEFORMAT mdy;

insert into SAMPLE values (1, 'x','x','x','x','2015-03-01 04:00:00.000');
insert into SAMPLE values (2, 'x','x','x','x','2015-03-02 04:00:00.000');
insert into SAMPLE values (3, 'x','x','x','x','2015-03-03 04:00:00.000');
insert into SAMPLE values (4, 'x','x','x','x','2015-03-04 04:00:00.000');
insert into SAMPLE values (5, 'x','x','x','x','2015-03-05 04:00:00.000');

insert into SUSERFLDS values (2, '03/02/15', '04:00');
insert into SUSERFLDS values (3, '03/04/15', '04:00');
insert into SUSERFLDS values (4, '03/05/15', '04:00');
insert into SUSERFLDS values (5, '03/06/15', '05:00');
```

---

```
set dateformat mdy;

with example as (
select CAST( compstartdate +' '+ compstarttime as datetime) as compdatetime
from superflds)
select *
from sample
where  1 = (
  select count(*)
  from example
  where DATEPART(dy, compdatetime) = DATEPART(dy, coldate) + 1
  and   DATEPART(hh, compdatetime) = DATEPART(hh, coldate) 
  and   DATEPART(mi, compdatetime) = DATEPART(mi, coldate) 
  )
```

Please ask any questions or add clarifications in the comments.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tested this and it isn't giving me what I'm looking for. I need to compare today's sample start date/time with yesterday's end date/time and find instances where they are not equal due to data entry error. Logically, today's sample(24-hour composite) starts when yesterdays sample ends. Also, LOCCODE and LOCDESC will be the only field that is the same for today's and yesterday's samples.

Answer (score -1):

You say only that the dates and times for the "previous day" must match. But then you match on the SAMPNO values. I'm guessing that SUSERFLDS enters the time the next day's sample is to be taken.

Your query starts alright except that your reference table would seem to be SUSERFLDS so that should be the first table listed. Then you want to match a record from SAMPLE that has the same sample number AND the same date and time.

To do the comparison, you can either turn the SAMPNO datetime into a string of the same format as the date string (mm/dd/yy) and extract the date part and the time part to compare to the strings from SUSERFLDS, or turn the date and time strings into a datetime value and just compare to the SAMPNO datetime.

Using the latter option, here is the query:

```
select  U.[SAMPNO],
        U.[Compstartdate],
        U.[Compstarttime],
        S.[LOCCODE],
        S.[LOCDESCR],
        S.[LOGBATCH],
        S.[LOGUSER],
        S.[COLDATE]
from    SUSERFLDS u
left join SAMPLE  s
    on  s.SampNo  = u.SampNo
    and s.ColDate = Cast( u.CompStartdDate + ' ' + u.CompStartTime as datetime );
```

Notice I use an outer join. That is so you will still see all the SUSERFLDS entries but with NULLs where the sample data is supposed to be for those samples with mismatching datetimes. This gives you an immediate indication of where the dates and times do not match. You can add

```
where  s.SampNo is null
```

and you will get *only* the SUSERFLDS entries where the sample datetime do NOT match. In that case, you can leave out all the S.XXX fields in the select list as they will always just show NULL.

However, that doesn't really tell you much. Wouldn't it be better if you could see the actual sample dates but only the ones that did NOT match?

In that case, drop the "left" to perform an inner join and change the join criteria to "not equals". Like so:

```
select  U.[SAMPNO],
        U.[Compstartdate],
        U.[Compstarttime],
        S.[LOCCODE],
        S.[LOCDESCR],
        S.[LOGBATCH],
        S.[LOGUSER],
        S.[COLDATE]
from    SUSERFLDS u
join    SAMPLE    s
    on  s.SampNo  = u.SampNo
    and s.ColDate <> Cast( u.CompStartdDate + ' ' + u.CompStartTime as datetime );
```

So now you see the SUSERFLDS date and time values and the SAMPLE datetime value but only for those entries that do not match. This lets you see what the problems are.

Comment: I like your answer, it is very thorough, but I'm afraid that you may have misinterpreted my problem. I am trying to find instances where the "Compstart(date/time)" for one day does not match the "COLDATE" for the previous day. "Compstart(date/time)" is in the SUSERFLDS table and "COLDATE" is the SAMPLE table. The two tables are related by "SAMPNO".

Comment: Let's see if I can simplify the problem further. Every day there is a new sample and it gets a unique SAMPNO. Each sample has a COLDATE which is the end of the 24 hour composite. Each sample also has fields for the date and time when the 24 hour composite was started. Logically, the **start** of today's sample needs to be the same as the **end** of yesterdays sample, right.  So I'm trying to find errors in data entry where the start and end date/time's don't match. Clear as mud, right?

Comment: Are you saying that for every Sample entry, there are several SUSERFLDS entries? And that you just to make sure that there is one of them that has the same date & time as the Sample entry?

Comment: I edited my post at the bottom. I added some explanation that I hope clears the problem up.

Comment: Why don't you create some sample data? Just a few rows of each table, with the data matching what you're looking for and one that does not.

Comment: Added some sample data to the original post.

Comment: OK, you've modeled yourself into a pretty corner here. The only possible connection between the Sample and Suserflds tables are the SampNo fields. But, as these are surrogate keys we cannot use their values to infer any relationship to the rest of the data. In particular, as they appear to be independent of each other, we may not assume that SampNo 11 occurs on the day after SampNo 10 or the day before SampNo 12. Since they are independently generated, we can't even infer that SampNo 10 of one table has any relationship with SampnNo 10 of the other table.

Comment: You could take the date from Sample table and search Suserflds table for a match. But if you don't find a match, you can't tell which row *should* have matched. If you find a hit, there is no way to tell if the hit was from the correct row. When you say, "that fixing the data types is not an option" do you mean that there is no way to change either of the tables? If that is so, you just may have to go to your boss and tell him you can't get there from here. Sorry.

Comment: I think that you are missing some key facts. First, SAMPNO for both tables are directly related. SAMPNO is the PK. Also, it will always be true that we want to compare one day with the the record that is exactly one day prior. for instance: `DATEPART(DAY,COLDATE)` would be compared to `DATEADD(DAY, -1,  COLDATE)`

Comment: By your own example, you say that "compstartdate/time for SAMPNO 12
does match COLDATE for SAMPNO 11". The values 12 and 11 are not related. The only valid relation between two surrogate keys is equals. The fact that so far in your data the key values for adjacent days differ by one cannot be trusted. You cannot infer *anything* about the data in a row from the value of a surrogate key. And like I said before, if you compare DATEPART(DAY,COLDATE) to DATEADD(DAY, -1, COLDATE), then you can't be sure that a "hit" is from the correct row. It will match any row(s) with the same date.